# C++ std::getline result string won't let me concatenate another string to it

Tags: c++, string, fstream, string-concatenation, getline

I am attempting to read data from a .txt file which contains nothing but a list of names. I want to do the following for each name:

```
1) read a name and store it in a string variable.
2) Add quotes to the name ("name")
3) make a map entry using each name (map["name"]= x)
```

I am using the std::getline function to read each line and I'm trying to add the quotes simply by using ( string name="\""+line+"\"" ).
The problem is that every time I add something to the end of the line string, nothing is added!

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream reader("input.txt");
    string line;
    string name;
    map<string,int> arr;
    int np=5;
    for(int i=0;i<np;i++){
        getline(reader,line);
        name="\"" +line +"\"";
        cout<< name << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my input txt file:

```
dave
laura
owen
vick
amr
```

this is the output I'm currently getting:

```
"dave
"laura
"owen
"vick
"amr"
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Add another `endl` to the output to test. I suspect you have a file that has different line ending conventions than the system you're reading it in.

Comment: Your code runs fine by me. How about `cout << line << endl; cout<< name << endl;`?

Comment: If I run on Linux, but use DOS line-ending conventions in `input.txt`, then it looks similar. The extra CR put the last double-quote to the far left in a terminal.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want to add quotes? Are you not getting confused by literal notation?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your input lines ends with \r\n, while your `getline` reads until '\n'. If that is true then solution is to remove manually \r char at the end of line:

```
getline(reader,line);
line.pop_back();
```

[edit]

or instead of `pop_back()`:

```
auto cr_pos = line.rfind('\r');
if ( cr_pos != std::string::npos )
  line = line.substr(0, cr_pos);
```